# Prove or disprove: $\operatorname{Adj} (A)$ is diagonlizable $\implies A$ is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, adjoint-operators

For $2X2$:
$$
A:\\
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
\operatorname{Adj}(A):\\
\begin{bmatrix}
d & -c \\
-b & a 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
So the statement is true.

The problem comes when it's $3X3$:
$$
\operatorname{Adj}(A):\\
\begin{bmatrix}
\left |\begin{matrix}
a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{32} & a_{33} 
\end{matrix} \right | & 0 & 0 \\
0 &  \left |\begin{matrix}
a_{11} & a_{13} \\
a_{31} & a_{33} 
\end{matrix} \right |& 0 \\
0 & 0 & \left |\begin{matrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} 
\end{matrix} \right |
\end{bmatrix}
$$ 
I'm not sure this implies that A is diagonlizable.
I've done some examples and the statement was true but I can't prove the general case.

**EDIT:**

I just realized that I confused **diagonal** with **diagonalizable** so you can ignore all my steps.

Comment: Your formula for 3-dimensional adjoint is incorrect.

Comment: You are right. Edited.

Comment: Still not right. Each of the nine entries is up to sign a 2 by 2 determinant.

Answer (score 11):

The result is not true. If $A \in M_n(\mathbb{F})$ is a non-diagonalizable matrix with $\operatorname{rank} A \leq n - 2$ then all the $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ minors are zero and so $\operatorname{Adj}(A) = 0$ is diagonalizable. For a concrete counterexample, you can take

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}. $$

Answer (score 4):

This is true if $A$ is invertible, because
$$
\operatorname{Adj}(A)=(\det A)A^{-1}
$$
and clearly an invertible matrix is diagonalizable if and only if its matrix is: if $A=SDS^{-1}$ is invertible, with $D$ diagonal, then
$$
A^{-1}=SD^{-1}S^{-1}
$$
(no diagonal entry of $D$ is zero, since $A$ is invertible). Multiplying by a nonzero constant has no consequence on diagonalizability.

If $A$ is not invertible, then the statement may be false as shown in levap's answer.